# Sending email from twig template

Tags: templating, emails, craft-features

Does anyone know of a way to send simple php mail from a twig template?

Something we can use like... {% mail 'Message', entry.userEmail %} or similar.

Would be good to not have to pre-define the content in a plugin.

Comment: Although not what the user was looking for, take a look at [my answer here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12824/how-can-i-pass-variables-to-emails-template-onbeforesendemail). Is that what you are trying to do? I can provide a better answer here if so...

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple plugin with just a Template Variable that sends the mail: https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/variables

Not sure if I'd put this kind of logic in templates though.